# Copy directory tree, changing the target of absolute symbolic links

Tags: symlink, file-copy

I wondered if there's an easy way to copy, scp, pipe tar, etc.
`host1:/base1/dir1`  to  `host2:/base2/dir1`. Other than the base directory, all the directory structure should be identical.

`host1:/base1/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/ contains a symbolic link file like this:

```
SYMBOLIC_LINK -> /base1/dir1/dir2/dir5/dir6/file1
```

I want the copy to have a symbolic link pointed to the same directory names, but with a different base directory:

```
SYMBOLIC_LINK -> /base2/dir1/dir2/dir5/dir6/file1
```

I'd like to do that on the fly without having to so some kind of sed or other search and replace to fix it after the copy.

Comment: Did you have a look at rsync? It can copy across hosts (via ssh) and has many options regarding smlinks. Search the manpage for "link", maybe there are some that help you do what you want.

Comment: I have not yet Lucas. I was hoping somebody had done this or similar before and had a quick answer. I will research rsync options though. Thanks. Wonder why I didn't get an email notification that you posted.